# add many hyperlinks using addHyperlink in xlsx

Tags: r, xlsx

I am using xlsx to make workbooks with several sheets, and in each I would like to add a column of hyperlinks, each row being different.  I followed the example in the reference manual

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows <- createRow(sheet1, 1:10) # 10 rows
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:8) # 8 columns
cell <- cells[[1,1]]
address <- "http://poi.apache.org/"
setCellValue(cell, "click me!")
addHyperlink(cell, address)
saveWorkbook(wb, "foo.xlsx")
```

which is pretty straight forward, but I would like to pass a vector of hyperlinks to `addHyperlink()`, and then a vector of display names to `setCellValue()`.  To this effect I tried:

```
 ...
 cell <- cells[[1:2,1]]  #I am assuming that cells is a matrix like object with 
                         #[[rows, columns]]
```

which gives the error

```
 Error in cells[[1:2, 1]] : attempt to select more than one element
```

Is there a clean way to do this, or is xlsx set up to loop over making `cell`?

Best
Sam

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use a `for` loop:

```
library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows <- createRow(sheet1, 1:10) # 10 rows
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:8) # 8 columns
links <- c("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978461/add-many-hyperlinks-using-addhyperlink-in-xlsx", 
           "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1599501/sam")
names(links) <- c("add many hyperlinks using addHyperlink in xlsx",
                  "User: Sam")
for (row in 1:length(links)) {
  setCellValue(cells[[row,1]], names(links)[row])
  addHyperlink(cells[[row,1]], links[row])
}
saveWorkbook(wb, "foo.xlsx")
shell.exec("foo.xlsx")
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid loops, your code works, but when rows is long, it slows down a lot and tends to cramp up memory (at least I have been getting memory errors when running too many w/o a restart of R)

Comment: Would be helpful is there was a CB.addHyperlink() function that could work on a CellBlock object by taking a vector of links